# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, vscode, instalacion, requests, modulos

Instalé la librería request usando `pip3 install requests` pero me sale este error:

File "c:\Users\Andres\Documents\Python_Curso\crawlers\crawlers1.py", line 1, in module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

y si intento instalarla de nuevo me sale que los requisitos están satisfechos

pd: tengo python 27, 3.9 y 3.10 instalados

Comment: si lo instalas con pip3 con que ejecutas el file con python3? o con python normal?

Comment: @Bryro con ambos sale el error

Comment: intenta haciendo un `where pip3` ahora te enviara la ruta donde se encuentra y veras que esta dentro de `Scripts` debes subir un nivel e ir a `\lib\site-packages` y ver si aparese request

Comment: @Bryro Aparecen las  carpetas requests y requests-2.27.1.dist-info y aún así no me detecta los módulos

Comment: ¿Lo instalaste en un entorno virtual o de manera global? Ya que podría ser conflicto entre python 3.9 y 3.10, Con que versión de python estas ejecutando tu crawlers1.py?

Comment: @KevinRamirezZavalza lo instalé de manera global, probé ejecutarlo con los 2 interpretes y me dicen lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, resulta que si ponía en la consola python --version me decía que tenia instalado la 3.8.8, yo estaba usando el interprete de la 3.10.2 así que copié las librerías descargadas de las 3.10 y las pegué en la 3.8, de todas maneras me gustaría saber como dejar la 3.20 como global